# Lectura de archivos locales, en particular con la función print en Python

Tags: python

Tengo un problema al copiar la dirección de un archivo local para que se lea en pandas. En particular con este código:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("C:\Users\zewei\Desktop\characters-simpsons.csv")
```

Sé que la dirección del archivo está bien porque lo he probado en otros sitios como google chrome y sí funciona.

El problema está en esto:

```
print("\U)
```

Que aparece en ...`("C:\U`..

No sé por qué me da error, supongo que se trata de algún caracter especial, como cuando queremos imprimir un salto de línea (`\n`). Pero entonces no sé cómo conseguir que se lea el archivo.

Comment: todo se arregla colocando `r'ruta'` y haciendo un `print(df)`

Answer (score 3):

Estás en lo cierto con tu suposición.
Esos "caracteres especiales" en realidad se llaman secuencias de escape. En tu caso \u sería un escape unicode. No se mucho de los escapes unicode, solo se que los usas sin querer.

Para leer el archivo sin que esas secuencias de escape estorben puedes aplicar una de las siguientes cosas:

#### 1-Usa / en lugar de \

La barra "normal" NO tiene ningún significado si se le pone una letra, numero o ambos delante. Por lo que podrías usarla para escribir directorios. Al menos en mi python eso siempre fue valido.

```
df=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/zewei/Desktop/characters-simpsons.csv")
```

#### 2- Usa \\

\\ es una secuencia de escape la cual representa al caracter \. Curiosamente, estoy usandola al escribir esta respuesta.

```
df=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\zewei\\Desktop\\characters-simpsons.csv")
```

#### Haz un raw string

Los raw strings son cadenas en las cuales las secuencias de escape no se toman de una forma especial. En Python, si quieres crear una tienes que colocar una "r" antes de la cadena. Esto hace que secuencias de escape como \u o \n no tengan ningún significado.

```
df=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\zewei\Desktop\characters-simpsons.csv")
```