# EJECUTAR MACRO CON PYTHON

Tags: python, excel, vba, macros, ejecutar

estoy intentando ejecutar un macro de un fichero excel (.xlsm) desde python 3.10

Hasta ahora he hecho:

```
import os
os.chdir('C:\Users\...DIRECTORIO DONDE SE UBICA EL EXCEL')  
#os.system("NOMBREFICHERO.xlsm!NOMBREMODULO.NOMBREMACRO")
```

Pero me salta el siguiente error en la 2/3 linea :

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes
> in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Espero que alguien pueda ayudar. Gracias!

Comment: Te recomiendo leer esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/466144/158880

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Lectura de archivos locales, en particular con la función print en Python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/466132/lectura-de-archivos-locales-en-particular-con-la-funci%c3%b3n-print-en-python)