# concatenar url python

Tags: python

Necesito abrir un archivo cuya extension es .odb( es de un programa de ingenieria que genera ese archivo). El caso es que, necesito que sea dinamico. Pongo un ejemplo:

```
name=lines[1]
odb = openOdb(path=r"C:\Users\Miguel\Desktop\post\\"+name+".odb")
```

Me explico. name lee una línea(olvidense de como leo la línea, es un ejemplo solamente), donde introduzco el nombre del archivo que necesito que me abra. El problema está que no me encuentra la ruta, que es una carpeta llamada post en el escritorio. El problema creo que está en la doble barra invertida del final, pero no sé como solucionarlo. Cómo puedo hacer?
Gracias

Comment: Y si la doble barra es el problema, por qué no la quitas?

Comment: porque entonces me coge "+name+" como string, no me coge lo que vale la variable

Comment: si lo imprimo tal cual está formulada la pregunta me sale esto:   
    C:\Users\Miguel\Desktop\post\\modelo_final.odb   donde name vale modelo_final, pero no me encuentra la ruta

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/466132/lectura-de-archivos-locales-en-particular-con-la-funci%c3%b3n-print-en-python/466144#466144. Te recomiendo además que busques otra forma de [formatear strings](https://www.freecodecamp.org/espanol/news/formato-de-cadenas-en-python-ejemplos-de-formato-s-sprint-en-python) que no sea la concatenación, ya que no suele ser buena idea usarla.

Comment: Puedes usar el módulo `pathlib` para el manejo de rutas

Comment: @MIGUELANGELDELCASTILLOHERA no me refiero a quitarla sin más... obviamente si no haces algo para arreglar tu string no va a funcionar. Tal como te menciona el compañero Dante S., concatenar strings no suele ser buena idea igualmente. El problema tiene pinta de venir originado por tu `r` al inicio del string, puesto que eso hace que no interprete las contrabarras \ si no que los tome literalmente. Prueba usando `f` para formatearlo: `f"C:\Users\Miguel\Desktop\post\{name}\.odb"` o usando alguna librería para manejo de rutas como menciona Christian.

Comment: @MIGUELANGELDELCASTILLOHERA el `r` que pones antes del string significa string raw, es decir se parsea directamente con doble `\\\`` a tu pc, lo cual no es correcto en windows. debes hacer: `path=f"C:\\Users\\Miguel\\Desktop\\post\\{name}.odb"`

Comment: L F muchas gracias por tu ayuda lo primero. Estoy un poco perdido porque no manejo muy bien esto de las rutas y necesito tener esto bien. He puesto literal lo que me dijiste y me sale el siguiente error: "SyntaxError: ('invalid syntax', ('Postproc.py', 16, 66, 'odb = 
#* openOdb(path=f"C:\\\\Users\\\\Miguel\\\\Desktop\\\\post\\\\{name}.odb")\n'))

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente la barra invertida es un caracter especial de Python que se usa por ejemplo en `\n` para una newline. Para utilizar la barra invertida en cadena de texto prueba a escribir la barra invertida dos veces, es decir:

```
name=lines[1]
odb = openOdb(path=r"C:\\Users\\Miguel\\Desktop\\post\\"+name+".odb")
```

Comment: me sigue sin encontrar la ruta, pero gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Si pones una `r` delante de la cadena estás diciendo que es una cadena de tipo "raw" en la que la barra invertida ya no tiene significado especial. Por tanto no necesitas duplicarla. De hecho, si la duplicas, estás metiendo en realidad dos barras. Yo creo que debería funcionar el poner `rf"C:\Users\Miguel\Desktop\post\{name}.odb"`

Comment: hola buenas. He intentado lo del raw y me sale esto: 'invalid syntax', ('Postproc.py', 14, 54"filename = 
#* rf"C:\\Users\\Miguel\\Desktop\\post\\{name}.odb"\n')). No sé que le pasa. Lo mismo es por lines[1]. lines [1] debe leer la linea uno de un fichero de texto, donde el usuario escribe el nombre como quiere que se llame el archivo, y con lo que pregunte lo abro, no sé si eso influirá.

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar problemas con la barra invertida y además ser más compatible con otros operativos, se recomienda utilizar la biblioteca `pathlib`.

Usando esta biblioteca (que forma parte de Python sin que tengas que instalar nada) el código sería así:

```
from pathlib import Path

name = lines[1] + ".odb"
filename = Path("C:/") / "Users" / "Miguel" / "Desktop" / "post" / name
odb = openOdb(path=filename)
```

### Actualización

Al margen de que uses o no uses `pathlib`, creo que el problema puede ser que `lines[1]` contenga un retorno de carro al final, el cual pasaría a formar parte del nombre del fichero y por eso no te lo encuentra. Puedes quitar el retorno de carro con un `strip()`.

Aquí te pongo otra solución que no usa pathlib, y que usa cadenas de formato "raw" para insertar el nombre sin tener que andar concatenando cadenas, lo que te daba problemas también con la barra delante de las comillas.

```
name=lines[1].strip() # El strip quita posible retorno de carro
filename = rf"C:\Users\Miguel\Desktop\post\{name}.odb"
odb = openOdb(path=filename)
```

Comment: Hola gracias por la ayuda. Parece interesantes, pero lo he copiado literal y me aparece:   ImportError: No module named pathlib, justo en la linea del import. Porqué pasa esto? Michas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Probablemente estás usando una versión muy antigua de Python. La biblioteca pathlib está presente desde Python 3.4, del 2014. Yo actualizaría python, que ya va por la 3.10 (a mayo de 2022)

Comment: estoy usando Spyder 3.9

Comment: La versión de spyder no está relacionada con la versión de python. Prueba a ejecutar con spyder un pequeño programa que haga `import sys; print(sys.version)` para ver qué versión de Python tienes instalada.

Comment: me aparece la 3.9.7

Comment: Pues no entiendo qué puede estar pasando. `pathlib` es un módulo estándar desde python 3.4 y ciertamete viene con la versión 3.9 que tú tienes, como puedes ver [en la documentación](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/pathlib.html) así que no me explico el error "No module named pathlib". Te pasa al ejecutarlo, o solo mientras lo escribes en el editor (a veces los editores intentan importar cosas para ayudarte con el completado automático de código, y si no están bien configurados pueden mostrar errores que en realidad no existen)